# Hidding annotations in Plotly/Python using a button

Tags: python-3.x, button, label, plotly, networkx

So I have constructed a network plot using Plotly. The output is fine. Now I wanted to add labels per each node of the network. In order to do so I used the Plotly annotations. `pos` holds the positions as `{node_id:(x,y)}` for every node in the network; `G` is my networkx graph.

```
layoutAnnotationList = []
for  k,p in pos.items():
    x = p[0]
    y = p[1]
    try:
        text = G.node[k]['hostname']
    except:
        text = k
    layoutAnnotationList.append( { 'x':x, 'y':y, 'text':text } )
```

After this I added the list `layoutAnnotationList` to the layout itself.

```
layout = { 'annotations': layoutAnnotationList }
```

Now, I've read [this](https://plot.ly/python/custom-buttons/) on how to add buttons to the layout, using the `relayout` method, but I really don't understand how to make those buttons to show or hide the annotations.

I created a `layoutButtons` list, I got to show them on the webpage, but I'm clueless regarding their functioning.

```
layout = { 'annotations': layoutAnnotationList, 'updatemenus':layoutButtons }
```

[image]

Any hint on how to use those?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, after reading carefully, the solution is to use the `update` method when creating the buttons.

```
layoutButtons = list([
                dict(type="buttons",
                     active=-1,
                     buttons=list([   
                        dict(label = 'Label:On',
                             method = 'update',
                             args = [{'visible': [True, True, True, True]},{'annotations':layoutAnnotationList}]
                             ),
                        dict(label = 'Label:Off',
                             method = 'update',
                             args = [{'visible':[True, True, False, False]},{'annotations':[]}]
                             ),
                            ]
                        )
                     )
                ]   
            )
```

I've got the idea from [here](https://plot.ly/python/custom-buttons/#update-button). Still do not know how to interpret the `{'visible':[True, True, False, False]}` dictionary inside the arguments, but it's working.

Answer (score 1):

This [code](https://plot.ly/python/sliders/#simple-slider-control) in the plotly documentation for Slider Controls suggests that the `{'visible':[True, False...]}` dictionary is mapped to the data list, with `True` meaning "display this index of my data list" and `False` "hide this index of my data list". In other words, you should have one True/False per data item.

In the code example, they initially set `visible` for each item in `data` to `False`

```
data = [dict(
        visible = False, 
        line=dict(color='#00CED1', width=6),
        name = ' = '+str(step),
        x = np.arange(0,10,0.01),
        y = np.sin(step*np.arange(0,10,0.01))) for step in np.arange(0,5,0.1)]
```

Then they toggle one to `True`, so some data is shown when the plot is loaded:

```
data[10]['visible'] = True
```

Next, when defining the steps for the slider, they reset all data items' `visible` argument to `False`, then toggle the i-th to to `True`:

```
steps = []
for i in range(len(data)):
    step = dict(
        method = 'restyle',  
        args = ['visible', [False] * len(data)],
    )
    step['args'][1][i] = True # Toggle i'th trace to "visible"
    steps.append(step)
```

When the i-th step is selected in the slider, the i-th data item will become visible.

In the original example of this question, we'd thus want set all `visible` arguments to `True` for the `Label:On` button, and all to `False` for the `Label:Off` button, so you could write:

```
'visible':[True] * len(pos)

'visible':[False] * len(pos)
```

Comment: As the code on the linked page might change or be removed over time therefore you should add the essentials here and keep the reference. Otherwise your answer might be invalid in the future.